# what is the substr? in the systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

```
Int fd;
String str;

fd = $fopen(path, "r");
Status= $fgets(str, fd);
cm = str.substr(0,1);
cm1= str.substr(0,0);
```

I want to know what is `substr` function? What is  the purpose above that??

Comment: @bunch It is interesting what is the sense of this expression  str.substr(0,0)? What  is its value? If its value is an empty string why is there used such compound expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **substr** function returns a new string that is a substring formed by characters in position i through j of str. Very similar to examples posted here.

```
module test;
  string str = "Test";
  initial
    $display(str.substr(0,1));
endmodule
```

The output will be:

```
>> Te
```

As you can see in section 6.16.8, [IEEE SystemVerilog Standard 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

**substr** function, as it name suggests, subtracts, or takes a chunk from a bigger string, in systemverilog.

Example:

```
stri0 = "my_lago";
stri1 = stri0.substr(1,5);
$display("This will give stri1 = %s" , stri1);
```

....
OUTPUT :- **This will give stri1 = y_lag**

Answer (score -1):

Substring: This method extracts strings. It needs the Position of the substring ( start index,  length). It then returns a new string with the characters in that range.

C# program  Substring

using System;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    string input = "ManCatDog";

    // Get Middle three characters.
    string subString = input.Substring(3, 6);
    Console.WriteLine("SubString: {0}", subString);
    }
}
```

Output

Substring: Cat

Comment: The length is 6 so the output is `CatDog`

Comment: This question is regarding SystemVerilog, not c#. SystemVerilog has different parameters than your answer (start index, end index) instead of (start index, length) of c#.